# Installing Keyboard hooks to specific process

Tags: c#, windows

I am using SetWindowsHookEx() function for installing a keyboard hook for my remote desktop application in C#. My code to start the hook is

```
private void Start()
{
    IntPtr handle = GetModuleHandle(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName);
    Proc = new HookProc(CallBackHook);
    IntPtr HookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(HookType.WM_KEYBOARD_LL, Proc, handle, 0);
    if (HookHandle == null || HookHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        Console.Write("Error while installing hook");
    }
}
```

The code works fine and captures keyboard activities for all processes but how to limit it for current process only. I tried specifying the thread id also but wont works.

```
HookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(HookType.WM_KEYBOARD_LL, Proc, handle, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
```

Can you please suggest me how to do that.

Comment: The 3rd argument must be null.

Comment: @HansPassant doesnt works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the best way will be to check in hook event handler if active window belongs to process which you are trying to hook

Comment: Usually Inside the process itself you have to add code inside the "Message pump" loop (in WinForms, the message pump is generally represented by Application.Run()). 

Are-you using WinForms ?

Comment: @RenaudBancelDAVEO yes i am using WinForms.

Comment: @Garath but how to do that.

Comment: @PankajPrakash are you trying to hook your own application?

Comment: @Garath yes I am trying to hook just my application only.

Comment: @PankajPrakash one more question: why you just not handle key press event (more on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx). Hooks are best for trying to handle key press in system wide.

Comment: @Garath thanks buddy I used your first opinion and it worked. And yes I should use the key press event.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to monitor the message inside your application, you can use

```
         Application.AddMessageFilter();
```